# getting < table of extent 0 > when using table() function to get table of frequency

Tags: r

Using RStudio from Anaconda, I am trying to generate a table of frequencies from a CSV file. When I run the code, instead of the expected table of frequencies, I get < table of extent 0 > as a result.

I tried running the same code in R (instead of RStudio) and it works as expected there. I am using RStudio from Anaconda, which already cause me a few problems upon reading code files, so I suspect it might be linked?

---

Code :

```
sn <- read.csv("social_network.csv", header = T)

table(sn$Site)
```

---

File content > head(sn):

```
  ID.Gender.Age.Site.Times


1         1;male;24;None;0

2  2;female;26;Facebook;20

3     3;male;54;Facebook;2

4   4;female;42;Facebook;7

5          5;male;54;None;

6   6;female;21;Facebook;3
```

---

Expected result:

```
Facebook LinkedIn  MySpace     None    Other  Twitter 

      93        3       22       70       11        3
```

Actual result:

```
< table of extent 0 >
```

Comment: @mt1022 You are right. I stopped reading after "File content" and overlooked `head(sn)`. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The column delimiter is not correctly set. Please read the file by specifying the correct delimiter:

```
sn <- read.csv('social_network.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
```